# How to have a  trailing space character in authors file for git svn

Tags: git-svn

Authors in my svn repo are as follows:

> $ svn log --xml | grep author | sort -u | perl -pe 's/.>(.?)<./$1 = /'

Output:

```
<author>ashfame</author>
<author>clean</author>
<author>clean </author>
<author>rocketweb</author>
```

But while cloning the repo for import using `git svn clone`, it halts in between saying `Author: clean  not defined in /home/ashfame/fun/authors-transform.txt file`

Notice the double space after clean, which means its the 3rd user `"clean "`.

**How do I format my authors file to have a space in username?** My current contents are as follows:

```
ashfame = Ashfame <mail@example.com>
clean = Yogesh Tiwari <yogesh.tiwari@example.com>
clean = Yogesh Tiwari <yogesh.tiwari@example.com>
"clean\ " = Yogesh Tiwari <yogesh.tiwari@example.com>
"clean " = Yogesh Tiwari <yogesh.tiwari@example.com>
rocketweb = rocketweb <rocketweb@rocketweb.com>
(no author) = Yogesh Tiwari <yogesh.tiwari@example.com>
(no author) = no_author
```

**Interesting discovery:** I tried importing the svn repo into git without any user mapping and I couldn't see anything related to "clean " user, only "clean" exists, so I am guessing this is some hiccup on svn repo. Any pointers on what can be done about it?

Comment: change author "clean " to "clean" **in SVN**?

Comment: @LazyBadger And moreover I would have to do something about the space in the method of renaming it too. Better I just map it to something or ignore it all together.

Comment: `svn propedit svn:author -r NN --revprop` for all revisions with author "clean "

Comment: @LazyBadger Seems like "clean " doesn't even exist. Appended the info at the end of the question. Can you check?

Comment: That last *might* be the space being lost when git-svn generates the default author info but *after* it looks the username up in the authors file.

Comment: @KevinReid So what should I do? Can I set it to ignore the users not found in authors file?

Comment: I don't have any information to solve the problem, sorry. Maybe look at git-svn's source code to see how it parses the authors file?

Comment: @Ashfame - you can try `svnadmin dump` and check usernames in dump-file. git-svn *may* trim() authors

Comment: @LazyBadger For now I have solved it by renaming authors in Git rather than dealing with SVN. Thanks! I will try svadmin if I happen to do such a thing again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't figure what the hiccup was with the SVN repo, so I just imported them without any author file. And then I renamed the commit author data using this script from [Github](http://help.github.com/change-author-info/):

```
#!/bin/sh

git filter-branch --env-filter '

an="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
am="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
cn="$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME"
cm="$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL"

if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "your@email.to.match" ]
then
    cn="Your New Committer Name"
    cm="Your New Committer Email"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "your@email.to.match" ]
then
    an="Your New Author Name"
    am="Your New Author Email"
fi

export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$an"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$am"
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$cn"
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$cm"
'
```

Save the above code in a file with a name say `change-commit-author-script.sh` and put the file in your repo root. Make it executable by `chmod +x change-commit-author-script.sh` and then run in by `./change-commit-author-script.sh`

And yeah don't forget to edit the script to fill in your name and email values.

Answer (score 6):

Had the similar problem with space in authorname.

Solve it using author-prog option, which allows you to use bash script, which will transform unknown authors.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "VisualSVN Server" ];then
    echo "VirtualSVNServer <svn.localdomain>";
fi
```

Comment: The option is called `--authors-prog` and not `--author-prog`.

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you already created a `users.txt` that you wanted to pass as `--authors-file` only to then realize that it doesn't work, here is a script that makes use of your existing `users.txt` and allows one to make additional customizations:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z ${GIT_SVN_USERS_TXT+x} ]; then
    echo "the environment variable GIT_SVN_USERS_TXT must be set to the path of your users.txt" >&2
    exit 1
fi

while read line; do
    # remove largest suffix and trim whitespace
    svn=$(echo ${line%%=*} | xargs)
    # remove smallest prefix and trim whitespace
    git=$(echo ${line#*=} | xargs)
    if [ "$1" = "$svn" ]; then
        echo "$git"
        exit 0
    fi
done < "$GIT_SVN_USERS_TXT"

if [ "$1" = "spaceatend " ]; then
    echo "VirtualSVNServer <svn.localdomain>"
    exit 0
fi

echo "Unable to find user $1" >&2
exit 1
```

Run it like this:

```
GIT_SVN_USERS_TXT=/path/to/users.txt git svn clone --authors-prog=/path/to/script.sh --no-metadata ...
```